# Query top N categories by aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to get the top N categories in one field. I am using the following query:

```
query= {
  "size": 30,
  "aggs": {
    "group_this": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_number.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

res = es.search(index="my_index", body=query, size = 30)
```

Unfortunately, I can only get the top 10 categories to show up in the response. I tried setting size = 30 but it keeps returning only 10. Where can I adjust how many categories I can show?

Comment: the `size` you've specified is used for while retrieving the document.Add the size after the `"field": "category_number.keyword"` [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `size` should placed under the `field`:

```
query= {

  "aggs": {
    "group_this": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_number.keyword",
        "size": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: follow-up question: what if I want to get the categories between the 5th and 30th? is there a handy way to exclude the top 1-5?

Comment: see this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html. if you have more questions please consider to open new Posts for them

Answer (score 1):

```
query= {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_this": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_number.keyword",
        "size" : 30
      }
    }
  }
}

res = es.search(index="my_index", body=query, size = 0)
```

Follow below link 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html